# mongoexport includes Ids and import will not ignore them

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to move some data between MongoDB databases using export/import.  I have an embedded document with an array field that I would like to update the other db with.

My first problem is trying to export just the field I need from the embedded document, I can get the entire subdoc, but not just the fields I want.  Okay, thats not a show stopper. Here is my export command;

```
mongoexport -d mydb -c mycollection -o ~/temp/mongoexport/myexport.json -f id_field,subdoc_field2 -q '{$query:{"subdoc.subfield":{"$exists":true}}}'
```

I get something that looks like this

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5060f491585dc52991000002" }, "id_field" : "R0410202", "subdoc" : [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50eb073d585dc586d600363e" },"subdoc_field1": "value1", "subdoc_field2": [intval1, intval2]}]}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5060f491585dc52991000003" }, "id_field" : "R0410202", "subdoc" : [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50eb073d585dc586d600364d" },"subdoc_field1": "value2", "subdoc_field2": [intval3, intval4]}]}
```

When I try to import it, it will not update the matching documents. Here is my command;

```
mongoimport  -c mycollection --db assr3_production --file ~/temp/mongoexport/myexport.json -f subdoc_field2  --upsert --upsertFields id_field
```

I get an error message "cannot change _id of a document".  I wasn't trying to change the ids, but it seems to attempt to anyway.

Is there a way to either get the export to not include the ids, or get the import to ignore them?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you drop the --upsertFields option, the import will complete, but I don't think that's what you want to do.  

The export wasn't giving you the fields you wanted because a) it only seems to do that in --csv mode and b) the subdoc is an array. If you specify it as subdoc.0.subdoc_field2, you'll get the field you want.    

The reason I think it's not what you want to do, is because the import  in upsert mode will replace the whole document with the fields you supply. So, if you only pick out a couple fields, that's all that will be in the docs after you import.

Comment: I just reread the docs here is the relevant line for --upsert, "Modifies the import process to update existing objects in the database if they match an imported object".  I read that to mean update not replace, but it appears to be trying to replace.  I was just looking for a way to move data around without writing code.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Steve07, you want to use a projection to explicitly remove the _id from your query results.

See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/#with-a-projection) for details.